# Truffle test error: Cannot create instance of Vault; no code at address

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, ganache, truffle-test

I'm trying to make a simple test in Truffle using Ganache where I call a function from a smart contract instance. This component will create a Vault and return me its address.

My truffle test does the following:

```
const VaultFactory = artifacts.require("./VaultFactory");
const Vault = artifacts.require("./Vault");

contract('VaultFactory', async () => {
    it("Should create a new Vault", async () => {
        let VaultFactoryInstance = await VaultFactory.deploy();
        let VaultAddress = await VaultFactoryInstance.CreateVaultContract.call();
        let VaultInstance = await Vault.at(VaultAddress);
    });
});
```

The `VaultFactory.sol` code that creates the Vault does the following (the Vault's constructor is empty):

```
function CreateVaultContract ()
    public
    returns(address)
{
    Vault newVault = new Vault();
    emit VaultCreation(msg.sender, newVault, VaultState.Created);
    return address(newVault);
}
```

The `VaultAdress` that I get is not empty, however, when I try to get the `VaultInstance`, it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot create instance of Vault; no code at address 0xed41bb9a56dad9b9d0901400f0a8de72d3cf1854
```

I tried doing a `web3.eth.getCode(VaultAddress);` to see if I had any code, but it returns me `0x0`.

So, my `VaultFactory` contract seems to be deployed and looks like it created a `Vault`. But for some reason, I can't manage to get its instance. Any idea why?

Comment: Try to replace `await VaultFactory.deploy()` with `await VaultFactory.new()`.

Comment: Also, the `CreateVaultContract` function is not constant (i.e., it changes the state), so you cannot `call` it and get the return-value directly (you need to `send` it as a transaction, and get the return-value from the event that this function emits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to get a working solution (even though I'm not sure it's the best one).

```
const VaultFactory = artifacts.require("./VaultFactory");
const Vault = artifacts.require("./Vault");

contract('VaultFactory', async () => {
    it("Should create a new Vault", async () => {
        let VaultFactoryInstance = await VaultFactory.deploy();
        let VaultReceipt = await VaultFactoryInstance.CreateVaultContract();

        //This returns the address of the newly created Vault
        let VaultAddress = VaultReceipt.logs[0].address;

        let VaultInstance = await Vault.at(VaultAddress);
    });
});
```

This way, I can get my Vault address and can get the instance of it. I then tried to call a function and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

let VaultAddress = await VaultFactoryInstance.CreateVaultContract.call();

should be:

let VaultAddress = await VaultFactoryInstance.CreateVaultContract();

Answer (score 1):

I had two problems

**Using .call() does not persist data**

```
Factory factory = await Factory.deployed()
factory.createChild.call()
```

This doesn't work, because call will return the code that would run on-chain, but it won't actually save anything on-chain. It's like you never called the function at all.

**Dynamic arrays don't need initialization**

```
constructor() {
   children = new Child[](1)
}
```

Don't do this. If you do, it will init 1 element as null.
If you then call `factory.children.call(0)` that element will be `0x00000...`
Obviously, there won't be any code at null.

**Working**

Solidity

```
contract Factory {
  event CreatedChild(address child);
  Child[] public children;

  function createChild() {
    Child child = new Child();
    children.push(child);
    emit CreatedChild(address(child);
  }
}

contract Child {}
```

Truffle

```
 it("should deploy child", async () => {
  const factory = await Factory.deployed();
  const tx = await factory.createChild();

  const childAddress = tx.logs[0].address;
  const firstChild = await factory.children.call(0);

  // console.log("tx return", childAddress);
  // console.log("array call", firstChild);

  assert.ok(childAddress !== 0);
  assert.equal(childAddress, firstChild);
});
```